# Android Cordova Media API not playing local media file

Tags: android, cordova

I am using Intel XDK + Cordova Media API to play a sound.

I put the .ogg file in /sounds/soundtrack.ogg. But this does not work:

```
var sound = new Media('sounds/soundtrack.ogg');
sound.play();
```

However, when I enter a remote file it will work, i.e:

```
var sound = new Media('http://remote.com/file.ogg');
sound.play();
```

Am I using the wrong path?

Comment: Your paths conflict a bit; what is the *full path* where the audio file is? I'm guessing you're either putting the file in the app's bundle or on the SD card, but I can't tell for sure.

Answer (score 0):

please use file path like  file:///mnt/sdcard/sounds/soundtrack.ogg in android ,i hope it will work for you .

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. But how do I know the full path of my app? I put the music files in the /sounds map of my app.

Comment: please follow this link to get url of any file http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_file_file.md.html